# Random forest k fold cross validation error for list class

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm trying to do k-fold cross validation with RF:

```
fit3 <- rfcv(x, y, data=trainset1, controls=cforest_unbiased, cv.fold=10)


testset1 <- as.data.frame(testset1)
pred1    <- predict(fit3, testset1, OOB=TRUE)
cor.test(pred1, testset$swl)
```

I encounter this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I'm sure that `testset1` is not a list.

Comment: How sure are you? What does `is.list(testset1)` return?

Comment: Ok, it returns true, but it returns the same error even though I unlist testset1

Comment: @nrussell `is.list` will return `TRUE` for data frames, because data frames are lists. What does `class(testset1)` return?

Comment: @Chris That was my point.

Comment: @nrussel but `predict` can take a data.frame as its second argument. Actually, I think OPs issue is with the `fit3` object. You are using the cross validation object to predict, when you should instead use `randomForest`

Comment: so why predict() doesn't work in here?

Comment: see how predict is used here: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/35647_8fffac2f551f48849cb28492e24c806f.html `predict` works, but not with `rfcv`.

Comment: I think OP needs to provide a completely reproducible example.

Comment: it looks like the object `fit3` is a list.

Comment: check `is.list(fit3)`

Comment: @Chris is right, rfcv can't be used in predict. I used randomForest previously but then I found using a separate testset always shows an overfitted result, so I am trying to do k fold. I have 2000 features, it's quite hard to select very useful features for RF model.